# django models: how to overcome 'through' ManyToMany option limitation

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a app for allowing users to create and manage user groups by themselfs.

The problem is I want to store which user added a new member to any group.

These are my models at the moment:

```
class UserManagedGroup(Group):

    leader = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('group leader'), related_name='leaded_groups')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=_('members'), through='Membership',
                                     related_name='managed_groups')

class Membership(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserManagedGroup, related_name='memberships')
    info = models.OneToOneField('MembershipInfo', verbose_name=_('membership information'))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'group']

class MembershipInfo(models.Model):

    date_added = models.DateField(_('date added'), auto_now_add=True)
    made_member_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user who made him a member'))
    membership_justification = models.TextField(_('membership justification'), blank=True, default='')


@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Membership)
def delete_membership_info(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.info.pk:
        instance.info.delete()
```

As you can see, I have a silly `MembershipInfo` model which would fit much better merged with `Membership` because of the nature of its fields. Also, `MembershipInfo`s life is bound to its `Membership` (which is why I had to create this post_delete signal connection).

I can't merge them because of this:

> Your intermediate model must contain one - and only one - foreign key to the target model (this would be Person in our example). If you have more than one foreign key, a validation error will be raised.

(In my case I can't use 2 foreign keys to User)

Now, this actually works but, I don't like it. It makes `Membership` instance creation tedious since I must always create a `MembershipInfo` instance first. Also, 2 queries instead of 1.

**QUESTION** Best way of storing 2 foreign keys to the same model (`User`) bound to my member relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just worked through a similar problem which included an intermediate model with two foreign keys to the same target. This is what my system looks like:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    receivers = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Connection',  related_name='senders',  symmetrical=False)

class Connection(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='outgoing')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='incoming')
```

I think this illustrates the main requirements for using two foreign keys to the same target in an intermediate model. That is, the model should have a `ManyToManyField` with the target `'self'` (recursive ManyToMany) and the attribute `through` pointing to the intermediate model. I think it's also necessary that each foreign key be assigned a unique `related_name`. The `symmetrical=False` argument applies to recursive relationships if you want them to be one-way, e.g. Node1 sends signals to Node2, but Node2 doesn't necessarily send signals to Node1. It is necessary that the relationship be defined with `symmetrical=False` in order for a recursive ManyToMany to use a custom 'through' model. If you want to create a symmetrical recursive ManyToMany with a custom 'through' model, advice can be found [here](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/).

I found all these interrelationships fairly confusing, so it took me awhile to choose sensible model attributes and related_names that actually capture what the code is doing. To clarify how this works, if I have a node object N, calling `N.receivers.all()` or `N.senders.all()` return sets of other Nodes that receive data from N or send data to N, respectively. Calling `N.outgoing.all()` or `N.incoming.all()` access the Connection objects themselves, through the related_names. Note that there is still some ambiguity in that `senders` and `receivers` could be swapped in the ManyToManyField and the code would work equally well, but the direction becomes reversed. I arrived at the above by checking a test case for whether the 'senders' were actually sending to the 'receivers' or vice versa.

In your case, targeting both foreign keys to User adds a complication since it's not obvious how to add a recursive ManyToManyField to User directly. I think the preferred way to customize the User model is to extend it through a proxy that's connected to User through a OneToOneField. This is maybe unsatisfying in the same way that extending Membership with MembershipInfo is unsatisfying, but it does at least allow you to easily add further customization to the User model.

So for your system, I would try something like this (untested):

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='member')
    recruiters = models.ManyToManyField('self', through = 'Membership',  related_name = 'recruits',  symmetrical=False)
    other_custom_info = ... 

class UserManagedGroup(Group):
    leader = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='leaded_groups')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='Membership', related_name='managed_groups')

class Membership(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='memberships')
    made_member_by = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='recruitments')
    group = models.ForeignKey(UserManagedGroup, related_name='memberships')

    date_added = ...
    membership_justification = ...
```

The recursive field should be asymmetrical since Member1 recruiting Member2 should not also mean that Member2 recruited Member1. I changed a few of the attributes to more clearly convey the relationships. You can use the proxy Member wherever you would otherwise use User, since you can always access Member.user if you need to get to the user object. If this works as intended, you should be able to do the following with a given Member M:

```
M.recruiters.all() -> set of other members that have recruited M to groups
M.recruits.all() -> set of other members that M has recruited to groups
M.leaded_groups.all() -> set of groups M leads
M.managed_groups.all() -> set of groups of which M is a member
M.memberships.all() -> set of Membership objects in which M has been recruited
M.recruitments.all() -> set of Membership objects in which M has recruited someone
```

And for a group G,

```
G.memberships.all() -> set of Memberships associated with the group
```

I *think* this should work and provide a 'cleaner' solution than the separate MembershipInfo model, but it might require some tweaking, for example checking the direction of the recursive field to make sure that recruiters are recruiting recruits and not vice-versa.

Edit: I forgot to link the Member model to the User model. That would be done like this:

```
def create_member(member, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        member, created = Member.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_member, member=User)
```

Note that create_member is not a method of Member but is called after Member is defined. By doing this, a Member object should be automatically created whenever a User is created (you may need to set the member fields to null=True and/or blank=True if you want to add users without initializing the Member fields).

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. 

The problem I see is that you still have 2 `ForeignKeys` to the same model. If the model is `Node`, `User`  or `Member` shouldn't make a difference. The docs say this: 

Your intermediate model must contain one - and only one - foreign key to the target model (this would be `Member` in your proposed solution). If you have more than one foreign key, a validation error will be raised.

Comment: My `syncdb` doesn't work if I have a model used with a `through` and this model has 2 references to the same model. Maybe your case worked because of being a relationship with `self`. I don't know...

Comment: Yes, it is necessary that the target model has a recursive ManyToManyField (a relationship with `self`) for this to work. I received the same error when setting up my models, but they do work now despite two foreign keys to the same model. You can see a couple more examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899779/many-to-many-relation-on-user-table-in-django) and [here](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/08/14/creating-recursive-symmetrical-many-to-many-relationships-in-django/).

Comment: If you think about it, that's really what it means to have two foreign keys pointing to the same model: members have some relationship with other members, through a membership. So you should define the relationship with `self` even if you don't provide a custom `through` model (if you don't, a generic one will be created that will have two foreign keys to Member).

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way that I see is to remove the ManyToMany field from your UserManagedGroup and to merge Membership and MembershipInfo.

You will able to access your members as well with the entry_set fields.